# URL in SSIS Derived Column

Tags: html, ssis, derived-column

I am trying to add a URL to a SSIS derived column expression. However, it errors. The column will be

I understand that it is possible, but I cannot get it to work correctly. Below is the last expression I tried. I placed it in a snippet because not all tags were presenting in my question. Additionally, the URL is bogus.

```html
"<a href=\""+"https://team.track.team.com/track/track.dll?View&I=14782&T=1000"+\"">"+"Click"+"</a>"
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW... I added a Data Conversion before (DT_WSTR, «length»).

Comment: Additionally, I tried the simplistic route starting the expression with ==.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSIS, but it looks like you have a `\"` outside of a quotes (after the URL string). Is that intentional? Specifically it looks like `+\"">"` should probably read `+"\">"`

Comment: Ever had one of those bang your head against the wall moments because you couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Your correction worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying but if your aim is to anchor the URL with 'click', then this seems to be working :

```
"<a href=https://team.track.team.com/track/track.dll?View&I=14782&T=1000>Click</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

You have a `\"` outside of a quotes (after the URL string).

Specifically it looks like `+\"">"` should read `+"\">"`

Comment: Thanks so much Nathan for catching this. The edit works.

Comment: I am attempting to add a column name to the below expression. Although it resolves in the expressions, it does not link from the table. "<a href=\""+"https://team.track.team.com/track/track.dll?View&I=UserID=1000">"+"Click Link Here"+"[ColName]</a>"